# Application Development with Offline Maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps, apple-maps

Is it possible to develop an application for Android and iOS that uses offline maps with routes and use GPS to navigate on them? (On foot and vehicle)

I found another answers but the question that is still in my head is, is it possible to user Google Maps or Apple Maps for this?

I also tried to search for a good 3rd party service that gives me what i want, but still nothing.

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Google Map for offline usage. It's against TOS (Terms Of Service)
(any caching  or downloading of google maps is  against Google Map TOS)
and is illegal.

Comment: I didn't understand anything of what you've written

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenStreetMaps(OSM) and a map serving service like Mapbox. OSM uses open mapping data that has been provided by users and other contributors and is free to use. With mapbox you can host your maps online but you can also store maps offline. With Mapbox Studio you can custom design your maps to create the kinds of visual hierarchy, affordances, and brand standards that your app needs. 
Check out these links for more details:
http://mapbox.com and
http://openstreetmap.org
Also Mapbox uses a pretty straight forward API and lots of documentation. Implementation into IOS is also very easy and you can almost just copy/paste to Xcode (almost).